# Differences between a class with static members and a namespace/module in typescript

Tags: typescript2.0

There are a lot of discussions about how and when to use static classes and how to achieve a real static class in typescript. But I have not found any explanation about the differences between a class with only static members paired with an unuseable constructor and a namespace/module.

How do them both affect the global namespace and what is the difference for the memory and usage?

Because in my opinion and what the official documentation says, it would be more easy to achieve the functionality of a static class by using a namespace construct. It is less code and more easy then to use a real class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always look at the compiled javascript output to see the difference. A namespace is an object that will be merged with other namespaces with the same name.

```
namespace A{
    export function b(){

    }
}
```

javascript output:

```
var A;
(function (A) {
    function b() {
    }
    A.b = b;
})(A || (A = {}));
```

A class is a function and a static member is a property of the function.

```
class A{
    public static b(){

    }
}
```

javascript output:

```
var A = /** @class */ (function () {
    function A() {
    }
    A.b = function () {
    };
    return A;
}());
```

Both, namespace and class, will occupy the same name "A" in the global namespace. From the perspecive of a client, there is no difference in accessing a static class member or a function inside a namespace:

```
A.b();
```

Personally, I don't use static class members or namespaces, i always define functions and variables at the top level inside a module, and use different modules to group different functions. 
The typescript homepage has a good topic about this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html

Comment: After some experiments I found out that namespaces are already deprecated and the modules too as you can read in tslint docs: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-namespace/ So what possibilites do I have to achieve the same behaviour now? I mean syntax wise.